# vim setting error under BufRead

Tags: vim

Running into a strange issue with my vimrc setting where I isolated to these 2 combination of lines if I use BufRead.

e.g.

```
au BufRead *.py
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
```

Now if I open a file with .py, I get error:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*.py":
E518: Unknown option: set
```

This only happens under au BufRead and individually each setting works but not in combination?

Comment: Interesting with | that it works but in my actual file I also had other set option that didn't use | before and they worked fine. So that's strange.

Comment: `|` is needed when you have multiple commands, `set` in this case. That's why `|` is not needed right after `au BufRead *.py` part. Read more `:help :bar`.

Comment: What I meant is that this worked w/ no error:
e.g.
`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py`
    `\ set shiftwidth=4`
    `\ set textwidth=79`
    `\ set expandtab`
    `\ set autoindent`

Answer (score 166):

If you want to use multiple `set`, separate with `|`:

```
au BufRead *.py
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4
```

Read more `:help :bar`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 17):

please use one `set` with space separated options:

```
au BufRead *.py set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```